# Anyone successfully using push notifications and getting feedback without returning to App?

Tags: react-native

Is anyone successfully using push notifications in react native and receiving data back from the notification without having to return to your App? For example, a user clicks on a notification and this updates your App's local storage.

Did you use the react native's built in component or another module?

I'm just looking for a high level overview of a working approach.

Ta,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I used [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to help doing the local notification and remote notification. they worked like charm.

Please follow the guideline of this libraries carefully

Cheer!